# How to using ng-repeat select all element, but without some class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, protractor

How can I use ng-repeat to select all elements but exclude all of them which have a class `bookmaker-disabled`.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVaXD.png)

I am using: `element.all(by.repeater('bookmaker in vm.bookmakers'))`

What needs to be added here to get a result without elements with class `bookmaker-disabled`?

Comment: provide some code what you did ?
try using angular.element(<the div>);

Comment: I am using: element.all(by.repeater('bookmaker in vm.bookmakers')) what need to be added here to get a result without elements with class bookmaker-disabled?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/aVV2eJ2O0ZePYutRInha?p=preview check this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at your screenshot, you add class 'bookmaker-disabled' when bookmaker.disabled is true. Well as per your code, you could add an `ng-if="!bookmaker.disabled"` to show only when not disabled, and remove elements which has disabled. In which case you needn't add the class.

Alternatively you could filter out those results which has bookmaker disabled, eg:
`<div ng-repeat='bookmaker in vm.bookmakers | filter: {disabled: false}'>`

Or you could use map reduce inside your controller if that was what you were looking for.

If you are using protractor, This might work:

```
element.all(by.repeater('bookmaker in vm.bookmakers')).filter(function(elem, index) {
  return elem.getAttribute('class').then(function(classes) {
    return classes.indexOf('bookmaker-disabled') === -1;
  });
})
```

Comment: I am a tester not developer and i not permitted to change their code. I just need to select an array from LI elements using ng-repeat, but without containing class bookmaker-disabled elements.

Comment: Currently to select all elements i am using element.all(by.repeater('bookmaker in vm.bookmakers')), is there some way to do that?

Comment: What tool are you using? Is it protractor? Your question is very misleading, you should mention that this is for testing and what testing framework you are using.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, it is Protractor.

Comment: In example that you provide above is some mistake probably:
[link](http://c2n.me/3zT6eUT)
check this link please

Comment: Ahh i found the issue, class is reserved word in framework )) ok Thanks you, that was helpful! You are cool!

Comment: Oh yes, should have put them in quotes. I have updated the answer. Please accept the answer if its the solution you were looking for.